# Errors when using pandas to_datetime function to convert a dataframe object to a datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-datetime

I'm new to using pandas and I'm trying to clean my data stored in a csv file. This csv file is saved in the same folder as my python file "dates.py". Specifically, I'd like to convert dates stored as strings into datetime values.

I have a column named "Order Date" in my csv file "Orders2022" which I've stored in a dataframe. An example "Order Date" entry is: 31-Mar-2022 08:00 PM EDT. All of the order dates have the same format.

While trying to convert these strings using to_datetime, I've manually provided the format as: format='%d-%b-%Y %I:%M %p %Z'.

This is the code I'm running:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5OCB.png)

This is the error message displayed:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNPY3.png)

I've tried removing the manual format and instead using infer_datetime_format=True but that also resulted in errors. I've also tried removing the utc=False but that doesn't work either. I'm not sure if the error is because of the "EDT" added to my order date? Could there be any issue correlating EDT to a timezone?

I've read up on the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), but I still can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Yes, it's the EDT not being recognized. Assuming you want just the local time then you can most simply remove the TZ using `df['Order Date']= df['Order Date'].str.replace(' EDT', '')` and then use `format='%d-%b-%Y %I:%M %p'` for the conversion. If you want to maintain the TZ info then you need to specify the difference from UTC as explained in the Docs.

Comment: @user19077881 thank you so much for your help! i went ahead and removed the timezone info and it worked